# Determine size of functions/stub/namespace in memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I have a couple of functions in a namespace called `stub`.
I have to determine the exact start address of the namespace and the end address, of at least the size of the namespace in memory (to copy these functions into another process).
While this worked perfectly in Visual C++ 2008 by adding a

```
void stub_end() { }
```

at the end of the namespace and using

```
size_t size = reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(stub_end) - reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(stub_start);
```

to determine the size of the stub.

This worked because Visual C++ preserved the function order as it is in the .cpp file, however that does not seem to be the case in Visual C++ 2010 anymore.

**How can I find out the size of the functions or the whole namespace/stub by using pragma directives, compiler/linker facilities or similar?**

Comment: Namespaces don't imply the storage for the contained types and functions, they are a syntactical tool.

Comment: I know, but basically the question is about any kind of bundle of functions (given a first and a last function, where the last function may also be empty, like in the example)

Comment: The compiler doesn't have to order the code in order of declaration and definitely won't as soon as optimizations are enabled.

Comment: I would be interested why you want to do this?

Comment: Remote Code Injection -> Getting the kernel32.dll address after starting a process with CreateProcess with THREAD_SUSPENDED. The Toolhelp32 API can not read the LDR table at that point yet.

Answer (score 1):

With the new push in security these days (heap randomization, [layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), etc..) I think this is going to be much more difficult. You may end up having to just copy each function individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and place each function in a different section, using the VC++ equivalent  GCC's **attribute** ((section ("name")))  http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_62.html and then use your technique, or you could place each function in a different source file.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ language provides no guarantees for finding addresses or sizes of namespaces. That said, venture into assembly language and linker instructions.

Many assembly languages have an opcode or mnemonic for placing code at specific addresses.  This allows a label to be set up to indicate the start of a memory area.  Some linkers have variables for obtaining segment starting addresses and sizes.  These would be user defined logical addresses.

In summary, use your assembly and linker tools to define public symbols for the namespace start and length or optionally the end of the segment.  In your C++ program, access these labels as `extern`.

Comment: Can you give examples for the directives in Visual C++?